# Injecting dependencies into an IConsumer

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, masstransit

Is there a way to inject into an IConsumer?

for instance

```
public class UpdateCustomerConsumer : IConsumer<ITestMessage>
{
    private IJimTest _jimTest;

    public UpdateCustomerConsumer(IJimTest jimTest)
    {
        _jimTest = jimTest;
    }
```

I've setup the Startup.ConfigureServices() using the MassTransit.Extensions.DependencyInjection nuget package.

```
        services.AddMassTransit(x =>
        {
            x.AddBus(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost:5672/"), h => { });

                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("test", ep =>
                {
                    ep.Consumer<Consumers.UpdateCustomerConsumer>();
                });

                cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(provider);
            }));
        });

        services.AddSingleton<IJimTest, JimTest>();
```

But _jimTest ends up empty.

Comment: what version of MT are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/containers/msdi.html), your configuration should look like this:

```
        services.AddMassTransit(x =>
        {
            x.AddConsumer<Consumers.UpdateCustomerConsumer>(); //added this line
            x.AddBus(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost:5672/"), h => { });

                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("test", ep =>
                {
                    ep.ConfigureConsumer<Consumers.UpdateCustomerConsumer>(provider); //changed
                });

                //if you use cfg.ReceiveEndpoint this one is not needed
                //you can remove cfg.ReceiveEndpoint and use below instead
                //cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(provider); 
            }));
        });

        services.AddSingleton<IJimTest, JimTest>();
```

Comment: Perfect thank you, i had tried putting the provider in before but i must have missed something.